# Read Only shared memory segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shared-memory

I'm struggling with shared mem on linux paltform.
Cosider the following code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define SEM_NAME "mysem"

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int     fd, zero = 0;
    int     *ptr;
    sem_t   *mutex;
    pid_t   PID = getpid();

    int mmap_prot = PROT_WRITE;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf(" Usage: Test [OPTION]\n\tW = Write Only\n\tR = Read Only\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (*argv[1] == 'W')
    {
        fd = open("Test_SHM", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, -1);

        if (fd == -1)
            perror("open");

        write(fd, &zero, sizeof(int));
    }
    else
    {
        fd = open("Test_SHM", O_RDONLY| O_CREAT, -1);

        if (fd == -1)
            perror("open");

        mmap_prot = PROT_READ;
    }

    ptr = mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), mmap_prot, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

    close(fd);

    if (ptr == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        perror("mmap");

        return 1;
    }

    // create, initialize, and unlink semaphore
    mutex = sem_open(SEM_NAME, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, -1, 1);
    sem_unlink(SEM_NAME);

    setbuf(stdout, NULL);   /* stdout is unbuffered */

    printf("Shared Mem ready..\n");

    while(1)
    {
        sem_wait(mutex);
        printf("PID %d Count: %d\n", PID, (*ptr)++);
        sem_post(mutex);

        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I launch the app for a read only shared memory I get, as expected, segmentation fault the first time `*ptr` is incremented inside main loop.

I'm working on a lib that abstract Linux shared memory.

This lib will be deployed to third part developers that will implement some processes for my application on an embedded target.

This lib will implement "global variables" between processes. I was wondering if I can avoid to develop `get` and `set` function and simply return address of allocated memory.

In case of wrong permission access I want to give to caller infos about what was wrong in its code. Read segmentation fault on terminal and process termination does not give user a good information.

**EDIT2**

After @Ctx answer I tried the following solution but it works the first segmentation fault. The second trigger standard segmentation fault and pogram terminate.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

#define SEM_NAME "mysem"

#define TEST 1

jmp_buf env;

void segvhandler(int arg) {
    longjmp(env, 1);
}

bool Test ( int *ptr, sem_t *mutex, pid_t PID)
{
#if (TEST == 1)
    signal(SIGSEGV, segvhandler);
#elif (TEST == 2)
    sig_t segvhandler_OLD = signal(SIGSEGV, segvhandler);
#endif

    int val = setjmp(env);

    if (val != 0)
    {
        printf("Segmentation fault catched.\n");

        sem_post(mutex);

        #if (TEST == 1)
            signal(SIGSEGV, SIG_DFL);
        #elif (TEST == 2)
            signal(SIGSEGV, segvhandler_OLD);
        #endif

        return false;
    }

    sem_wait(mutex);
    printf("PID %d Count: %d\n", PID, (*ptr)++);
    sem_post(mutex);

#if (TEST == 1)
    signal(SIGSEGV, SIG_DFL);
#elif (TEST == 2)
    signal(SIGSEGV, segvhandler_OLD);
#endif

    return true;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int     fd, zero = 0;
    int     *ptr;
    sem_t   *mutex;
    pid_t   PID = getpid();

    int mmap_prot = PROT_WRITE;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf(" Usage: Test [OPTION]\n\tW = Write Only\n\tR = Read Only\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (*argv[1] == 'W')
    {
        fd = open("Test_SHM", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, -1);

        if (fd == -1)
            perror("open");

        write(fd, &zero, sizeof(int));
    }
    else
    {
        fd = open("Test_SHM", O_RDONLY| O_CREAT, -1);

        if (fd == -1)
            perror("open");

        mmap_prot = PROT_READ;
    }

    ptr = mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), mmap_prot, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

    close(fd);

    if (ptr == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        perror("mmap");

        return 1;
    }

    // create, initialize, and unlink semaphore
    mutex = sem_open(SEM_NAME, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, -1, 1);
    sem_unlink(SEM_NAME);

    setbuf(stdout, NULL);   /* stdout is unbuffered */

    printf("Shared Mem ready..\n");

    while(1)
    {
        Test (ptr, mutex, PID);

        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're trying to modify the contents of **read-only** memory.  What do you expect would happen?  Read the man page:  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html

Comment: @AndrewHenle That the modification is discarded.

Comment: the posted code, compiled with `gcc` on ubuntu linux 14.04  cause the compiler to output 9 messages, of which 4 are error messages. The posted code is missing  statements:  `#include <sys/types.h>`
`#include <sys/stat.h>`
`#include <fcntl.h>`
`#include <unistd.h>`    Strongly suggest when compiling, to enable all warnings, then fix those warnings

Comment: @user3629249 You right. I tried with gcc on Debian 8.3. My code was from my autotool project arvv7 cross compiler. Those include are on my standard .h template. Thanks. I edited.

Comment: Something is inconsistent here.  There's recognition that the mapping is read-only, but also a desire to write to the mapping.  Why the inconsistency?

Comment: @ash I'm working on a lib that abstract òinux shared memory. This lib will be deployed to third part developers that will implement some processes for my application on an embedded target. This lib will implement "global variables" between processes. I was wondering if I can avoid to develop `get` and `set` function and simply return address of allocated memory. In case of wrong permission access I want to give to caller infos about what was wrong in its code. Read segmentation fault on terminal and process termination does not give user a good information.

Comment: I understand the desire to tell another programmer they've got the wrong memory permissions.  That's really tough to automate reliably.  Why not document the API requirement (writable memory) and diagnostic guideline (if you get SIGSEGV, check the memory perms).  If they have code-level access, there's no stopping another "C" dev from making pointer mistakes - and effort to eliminate that possibility rarely yields anything but more confusion (I have a lot of experience in this area).

Comment: @ash I'm used to do what you wrote. A well documented code and Doxygen is my salvation. It is usual that coders (those I usually dealt with) are lazy and don't spend time reading my docs. I'm sure they willpay attention to a red string on their terminal. ;)

Comment: Some folks are doomed to learn the hard way.  Not much you can do to help them ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to proceed if the modification doesn't work, you can install a signal handler for SIGSEGV and use (sig)setjmp/longjmp to continue execution at a defined point:

```
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

jmp_buf env;

void segvhandler(int arg) {
    siglongjmp(env, 1);
}

void somefunc(void) {
    char *ptr = NULL;
    signal(SIGSEGV, segvhandler);
    if (!sigsetjmp(env, 1)) {
        // Direct invocation, try the memory access
        *ptr++;
    }
    signal(SIGSEGV, SIG_DFL);
}

int main (void) {
    while (1) {
        somefunc();
        printf("One more iteration...\n");
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); // Never reached
}
```

`sigsetjmp(env, 1)` also saves the blocked signals in `env`, when it's second argument is non-zero and `siglongjmp()` then restores these. Otherwise, the signal will still be blocked after `longjmp()`, since it is not a real *return* from the signal handler.

Keep in mind that you should only have the handler installed directly before you make the memory access in question and deinstall it afterwards.

Comment: Good. I'll give it a shot tomorrow.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work as I expected. It work the first time, but the second time it goes directly to _segmentation fault_. I found [THIS](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1318.htm). `longjmp` is not the correct way to do something like a C++ `try catch`

Comment: @LPs It should work fine, can you see from gdb where it segfaults the second time? Do you call unsafe functions in your signal handler? Perhaps you can provide the actual code or a mcve where it segfaults the second time.

Comment: While catching this can be done, it's generally considered a terrible thing to do.  Consider, for example, if the fault happens because of bad pointer handling - so then what will be the result in the application?  While this specific case has a recognized cause, other code in the application that might trigger additional SIGSEGV activities will end up going through the same handling... tracking down such bugs will become a nightmare.

Comment: @Ctx I updated my question with code.

Comment: @ash That's why you should enable the handler only in the part where you expect it and disable it after that, as I wrote.

Comment: @Ctx That's great. It works like a charm. I also found out [THIS](http://www.programering.com/a/MjN1UTMwATg.html) Veri useful.

Answer (score 2):

Per the `mmap()` [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html):

```
   Use of a mapped region can result in these signals:

   SIGSEGV
          Attempted write into a region mapped as read-only.
```

Comment: Ok. Good, but there is something I could do before the SIGSEGV to check permission on shared memory and avoid segmentation fault?

Comment: Generally, no.  It's typically a contract with the function/code in question - if a writeable memory area needs to be given, the caller needs to solve it.  If the function "optionally" writes, then it can take an argument that tells it whether to write or not.

Answer (score 0):

a few minutes with the debugger shows the program crashes on the call to `sem_wait()`.

if, after the call to `sem_open()` insert:

```
    if( SEM_FAILED == mutex )
    {
        perror( "sem_open failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
```

then move the statement:

```
sem_unlink(SEM_NAME);
```

to before the statement:

```
mutex = sem_open(SEM_NAME, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, -1, 1);
```

then it will become obvious that the remaining problem is in this statement:

```
printf("PID %d Count: %d\n", PID, (*ptr)++);
```

which causes a bus error signal to be raised. this bus error signal occurs on the very first pass through the `while()` loop.

there is a simple cause.

the `printf()` statement, last parameter is trying to both read and write the memory mapped file, but the memory mapping was only for (depending on the command line parameter) either 'PROT_READ' which allows reading or 'PROT_WRITE' which allows writing.  the parameter to the call to `mmap()` needs to include both capabilities AND the call to `open()` also needs to 
have the mode: `O_RDWR`.  (the open() and the mmap() modes need to match

Comment: Thanks for your time. The problem is known. What I'm looking for is a way to implement a so call `try` `catch` for my specific case. Read comments and edits on my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the corrected code after Ctx answer. I also found out [THIS](http://www.programering.com/a/MjN1UTMwATg.html) that is useful to understan why longjmp is not the right solution with signals.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

#define SEM_NAME "mysem"

#define TEST 1

jmp_buf env;

void segvhandler(int arg) {
    siglongjmp(env, 1);
}

bool Test ( int *ptr, sem_t *mutex, pid_t PID)
{
#if (TEST == 1)
    signal(SIGSEGV, segvhandler);
#elif (TEST == 2)
    sig_t segvhandler_OLD = signal(SIGSEGV, segvhandler);
#endif

    int val = sigsetjmp(env, 1);

    if (val != 0)
    {
        printf("Segmentation fault catched.\n");

        sem_post(mutex);

        #if (TEST == 1)
            signal(SIGSEGV, SIG_DFL);
        #elif (TEST == 2)
            signal(SIGSEGV, segvhandler_OLD);
        #endif

        return false;
    }

    sem_wait(mutex);
    printf("PID %d Count: %d\n", PID, (*ptr)++);
    sem_post(mutex);

#if (TEST == 1)
    signal(SIGSEGV, SIG_DFL);
#elif (TEST == 2)
    signal(SIGSEGV, segvhandler_OLD);
#endif

    return true;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int     fd, zero = 0;
    int     *ptr;
    sem_t   *mutex;
    pid_t   PID = getpid();

    int mmap_prot = PROT_WRITE;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf(" Usage: Test [OPTION]\n\tW = Write Only\n\tR = Read Only\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (*argv[1] == 'W')
    {
        fd = open("Test_SHM", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, -1);

        if (fd == -1)
            perror("open");

        write(fd, &zero, sizeof(int));
    }
    else
    {
        fd = open("Test_SHM", O_RDONLY| O_CREAT, -1);

        if (fd == -1)
            perror("open");

        mmap_prot = PROT_READ;
    }

    ptr = mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), mmap_prot, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

    close(fd);

    if (ptr == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        perror("mmap");

        return 1;
    }

    // create, initialize, and unlink semaphore
    mutex = sem_open(SEM_NAME, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, -1, 1);
    sem_unlink(SEM_NAME);

    setbuf(stdout, NULL);   /* stdout is unbuffered */

    printf("Shared Mem ready..\n");

    while(1)
    {
        Test (ptr, mutex, PID);

        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```